# When to use animations in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, game-engine

I'm currently making my first game in unity. I came through all the tutorials on their site and i have one doubt. There are many situations when I can use either animation or just add force(or do something else). For example, if in my game player hits something it should fall and i can make it fall by animation or by just adding force. Both of these solutions are good for me. Can somebody more experienced in making unity games tell me are there any good rules for deciding what should I use? Are any of these for example more performance-friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on what your game is, and what kind of scale.

Falling objects that interact with other dynamic options? Physics is usually the best answer.

Just want something to move off screen then go away? Animation can make sense, but there are other options too without using physics.

Using lots of objects? Physics is a good way to handle it.

Using thousands of objects? Physics may be too much, will need to think of other ways.

Your question is really vague so can't give anything but a vague answer back.

However, for your first game, I will say don't worry too much about optimizing and make it simple at first. As you learn, you will understand what can be trimmed/changed later on.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Maybe you can help me a little bit with my current game. I am making a lot of balls that will be hung on the ceiling and will swing. There won't be more than 50 balls at one time. They aleso won't hit each other. What will be better in this case? I think the animation will be better beacuse I want them to swing all the time and not slow down and i don't exactly know how to do it with physics.

Comment: If you want them to swing at a uniform rate, not interact with anything and never slow down... animation would be a good choice